# Trying to run a WP Engine site locally but it keeps redirecting

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wpengine

I'm trying to run a wordpress site that is currently being hosted by Wordpress Engine locally. I followed the WP Engine instructions and did a find and replace on the sql file:

https://wpengine.com/support/best-practices-uploading-wp-engine-site-another-environment/

But it's still being redirected to a site-name.wpengine.com  url. When I do a search in the folder I don't find that url anywhere and it's been removed from the db by my find and replace. Is there somewhere else that might be cached in the files that might be causing that? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by defining the new urls in the wp-config like this:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://new-url.test'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','http://new-url.test');
```